# Parsing a string to date gives a completely different date in Android

Tags: java, android, date-parsing

The string is of the format `dd/mm/yyyy`

I am parsing using the following code:-

```
Dateformat dateformatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, ''yy");
dateformatter.setLenient(false );

String temp = "7/07/2017"
Date date = null;
try {
  date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").parse(temp);
}
catch(ParseException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
}

dateformatter.format(date);
```

The value that I get for `date` is `Sat Jan 07 00:07:00 GMT + 10:00 2017`

After formatting I get `Sat, Jan 7, '17`

The value I expect is `FRI Jul 07, '17`

Comment: Take a look at javadoc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html - lowercase `m` parses the minutes. To parse the month, use the uppercase `M`

Comment: Yes @Hugo I missed the case sensitive data in the date. Thanks for pointing out

Comment: In case you want a more modern solution to your task, since you are on Android, get [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) and do `LocalDate.parse(temp, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d/MM/yyyy"))`. This would also have caught your (very common) mistake with lowercase `mm` (and given you a rather cryptic error message, but better than no error message).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this line

```
date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy").parse(temp);
```

In the SimpleDateFormat, Month is denoted with M and not m.

> M - Month in year (context sensitive)
>
> m - Minute in hour

Change this to

```
date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy").parse(temp);
```

For more details, check the official documentation of [SimpleDateFormat](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Silly of me Mistake that. Thank you

Comment: It's a very, very common mistake.